# Why every time datatable rows count is doubled when i click on next record button in c#?

Tags: c#, sql

I am developing windows form application so i get the data from the table
  in sql server and stored the data in a data-table.

After that i checked this condition in my code:

```
if(dt.Rows.count>0)
```

Then,

Enter into the loop and assign values to the textboxes.Everthing is fine.

EX:

```
int count=0;    //Globally
```

In my Next_Record function:

```
if(dt.Rows.Count>0)
{
     txtWardId.Text = dt.Rows[count]["id"].ToString();
     count+=1;  
}
```

Then i defined one count variable globally then increment that variable
  Every click on (Next Record button) so it give another record fine.But 
  dt.Rows.count this gives the double value. (Means if the rows count is 7
  then next click the rows count is 14 and third click 21...like this)

This is my connection:

```
            SqlDataReader _reader;
            cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = openConnection();
            cmd.CommandText = Text;     //Assign the SP Name to Command Object
            cmd.CommandType = CmdType;  //Assign the SP Type to Command Object

            _reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();  //Execute the SP 
            dt.Load(_reader);
            _reader.Close();
            return dt;
```

What's the problem can you solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Please edit your question and add [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Maybe you are filling the table everytime without clearing it first. But that's just guessing because you haven't shown the code where you fill the table.

Comment: Are you maybe adding to your count in your loop method?

Comment: @Tim, I am filling this table from sql database.

Comment: @Huntt, No in if condition only i incremented count variable.

Comment: @Nag: i know that you're filling it from a sql database, you have mentioned it already in the question. But my point was that you might fill it  with a `TableAdapter` which `ClearBeforeFill` is set to `false`.

Comment: @Tim: i am not using TableAdapter i assigned datatable dt object directly to the textboxes.as shown above code.

Comment: @Tim,I am filling records into datatable after calling ExecuteReader()

Comment: @Nag: but the problem must be there because not the `count`-field has the wrong value but `dt.Rows.Count` , so the table contains double amount of rows.

Comment: @Tim. Yes count filed doesn't show any wrong value.But dt.Rows.Count only shows double of the row every click.

Comment: @nag: so you now know where you have to look, but you haven't shown that code, so we can't help you further without simply guessing.

Comment: @Tim:sorry actually i don't know where i have to look

Comment: @Nag: where you fill the table because it will be definitely filled when it should not be filled. Why you fill it everytime when you click the button?

Comment: @Tim:Yes,but actually i want to assign 2nd record values to the textboxes then how ?

Comment: Do you .Clear() the datatable before loading it?

Comment: Btw your if clause should not check if there are any rows in the table but if the row you want to access actually exists like this: `if(dt.Rows.Count > count)` or you could get a IndexOutOfRangeException when you call `txtWardId.Text = dt.Rows[count]["id"].ToString();`

Comment: You have to post the complete code to make it clear to everyone and understand the problem. you didn't specified where you write the code for connection and where you called it. Without that information not possible to understand where exactly the problem is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are adding the rows to the table always when you click on the `Next_Record`-button. [`DataTable.Load`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7x8ccbsb(v=vs.110).aspx) will merge new rows with existing rows.

You have two options:

1. Don't load the table on each `Next_Record`-click, it's not clear why you need it at all.
2. `Clear` the table first

   ```
   dt.Clear();  // or dt = new DataTable();
   using(var _reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
       dt.Load(_reader);
   ```

One thing to note, [`DataTable.Load`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7x8ccbsb(v=vs.110).aspx) merges new rows with existing. But how depends on the [`LoadOption`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.loadoption(v=vs.110).aspx) value passed to `Load`(default is `PreserveChanges`). But it can only merge rows when the primary key is defined. Otherwise those rows are never merged and added to the existing table.

Also note that your `if` condition is not complete:

```
if(dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
     txtWardId.Text = dt.Rows[count]["id"].ToString();
     count += 1;  
}
```

This fails if `count` is greater or equal `dt.Rows.Count`. I would start at record one again:

```
if(dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
     if(count >= dt.Rows.Count)
         count = 0;
     txtWardId.Text = dt.Rows[count]["id"].ToString();
     count++;  
}
```